# C++ - friend operator cannot access private data members

Tags: c++, private-members, friend-function, member-access

I am trying to overload an operator for a class:

```c
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Complex{
    float re, im;
public:
    Complex(float x = 0, float y = 0) : re(x), im(y) { }
    friend Complex operator*(float k, Complex c); 
};

Complex operator*(float k, Complex c) {
    Complex prod;
    prod.re = k * re; // Compile Error: 're' was not declared in this scope
    prod.im = k * im; // Compile Error: 'im' was not declared in this scope
    return prod;
}

int main() {
    Complex c1(1,2);
    c1 = 5 * c1;
    return 0;
}
```

But the friend function doesn't have access to the private data. When I add the object name, the error is resolved:

```c
Complex operator*(float k, Complex c) {
    Complex prod;
    prod.re = k * c.re; // Now it is ok
    prod.im = k * c.im; // Now it is ok
    return prod;
}
```

But according to the notes that I am reading, the first code should work without error. How can I fix the error without adding the object name (`re` instead of `c.re`)?

Comment: The `friend` functions are free functions. Not class member functions, so there is no implicit `this->`.

Comment: `c.re` is private member access on an instance of the class allowed because of `friend`. Your function is not a member function.

Comment: Marking it as `friend` implies that it is a non-member function. So which `re` and `im` should be accessed if there is no `this` object and there is no implicit `this->`?

Comment: Obviously your notes are not correct

Comment: So this means the notes are wrong or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, either your notes are wrong or you are missing something.

Comment: @WernerHenze thanks. So you mean there is no way, right?

Comment: The change you did with the additional `c.` is the correct solution.

Comment: @WernerHenze ok thanks. Now I am sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first `operator*` case, `re` and `im` are completely unknown to the compiler as the function `operator*` in this case is in a global space (scope).

In the second example of `operator*` you're giving `re` and `im` meaning by using an object of a class Complex `c` - in this case the definition of a `class Complex` is known to the compiler (is defined above) and it's members `re` and `im` are known too - that is the reason why you're not getting an error message in the second example.